# Is there a working simple example of postMessage working with a sandboxed page?

Tags: google-chrome-app

Looking at the postMessage example in this doc: http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_external.html#postMessage

It seems to suggest that the sandbox page would have the event handler registered synchronously, otherwise how is it supposed to ever get the postMessage event?

I guess this goes along with the bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154662
It seems you can't use window callbacks to send a postMessage to the sandboxed iframe, however there is mention of a workaround where you use a page that contains an iframe to the sandboxed page.  Only problem here is it's still unclear how/when the event fires and where it's visible...

This sandbox stuff appears to be very complicated and the documentation around it is misleading and/or outdated.  Does this example even makes sense?   Is it possible to send a message to the background page without first getting a message and recording the event.source?

How do you register an event listener in the background page to respond to messages send back from the sandboxed page?   So many questions here, and all I have is a broken example.

Comment: After some playing around, this seemed to work: 
`setTimeout(function() {
  win.contentWindow.frames[0].postMessage('I just called... to say... hi.', '*');
}, 100);`

But it seems pretty crazy to need to do this with a timeout.

Comment: I can't answer your question as it's phrased. But you're right: the example is a little too glib. It's technically correct, because it indeed "posts a message to the sandboxed page it opens." It's just not a very useful example because it'll be unreliable. Note the WHATWG spec's advice that "where a message is to be sent to the Window of newly created child iframe, authors are advised to have the child Document post a message to their parent announcing their readiness to receive messages, and for the parent to wait for this message before beginning posting messages."

Comment: I've worked my way through it.  Unfortunately, the answer is not concise, but it gets the job done and does indeed work they way I'm guessing they intended.  I'll try to answer my own question here later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples on the chrome-app-samples on github is more what you're looking for. Here's the sandboxed page adding the event listener to respond to events: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox.html

And here's the background page using `postMessage`: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/sandbox/mainpage.js

The github examples are much more rich than the ones on the documentation. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples has examples of just about everything you could need to do.